# Outlook Application_NewMailEx not working on startup

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2007

I am using a `Application_NewMailEx` to treat all emails received. 
It works fine on emails received while Outlook is open.

However on startup, the `Application_NewMailEx` does not get called by received emails.

I tried using a `Application_Startup` but it is called before emails are received ==> does not work.
There is no application.ontime to delay the startup macro...
`Application_NewMail` does the same.

How can it be done?

```
Private Sub Application_NewMailEx(ByVal EntryIDCollection As String)
    INIT_FOLD
    TreatMsg Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetItemFromID(EntryIDCollection)
End Sub
```

Comment: can you post some of your addin code?

Comment: Hi, there is no addin, just code in a module and thisoutlooksession. I will add it

Comment: SInce addin is loaded when outlook starts, so its unlikely that the new mail event get fired on startup. You can delay the new mail processing if you maintain information of all the mails.

Comment: the point is that there is no application.ontime  or application.wait as far as I know... so Application_Startup is too early, and  Application_NewMailEx does not seem to be already triggered. I dould use an external code to do the delay, but it's ugly.

Comment: Is that all the code you have on ThisOutlookSession?

Comment: @0m3r : I hadn't seen your question. No I also have a code that sends a new email, intended to be called from another program. The solution here under does not work really great actually, most of the time it does not trigger correctly on startup.

Comment: Application_Startup should work unless your not setting up correctly,  I can post example if your interested?

Comment: @0m3r : application_startup does get triggered. However it is triggered before the mails received before startup show up. Therefore I cannot treat those mails using application_startup . I tried using application_startup to launch a VBS that delays the task and does the treatment of message. But this is really bogus.

Comment: To trigger when item is being added to Inbox see example blow....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NewMailEx event will fire only for the messages received while your code was running. It will not fire for the emails received in your (Exchange?) mailbox before that.

You can either process the unread emails in the Inbox on startup (`Items.Restrict` or `Items.Find/FindNext`) assuming that new unprocessed messages are still unread or (in case of cached mode) use `Items.ItemAdd` event on the Inbox folder - it will fire when your OST file is being synchronized with the remote mailbox.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. When outlook is open, no code running, NewMailEx gets called on every message received.
I'll check out the Items.ItemAdd, thanks.
Right now I bypassed the problem through an ugly code: outlook launches on startup a VBS that waits a few seconds before calling a outlook VBA code that treats the latest message till it sees a read one. Ugly but bypass the lack of application.ontime in outlook.

Comment: I looked up, indeed the Items.ItemAdd is efficient. I prefer the NewMailEx when outlook is open (one event per mail, even if they are simultaneous, unlike items.add, one event per block of mails), so I replaced my ugly code by the Items.ItemAdd, but on first NewMailEx I unload it. So far so good, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

*Here is an Example on how to setup Application Startup and trigger your vba when **`MailItem`** is add to Inbox*

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items
Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim Inbox  As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set Items = Inbox.Items
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then
        Example Item ' call sub
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub Example(ByVal Item As Object)
    Debug.Print Item.Subject ' Immediate Window
End Sub
```

***[Application.Startup Event (Outlook)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869298.aspx)*** and **[Items.ItemAdd Event (Outlook)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869609.aspx)**

> *<sub>**[Items.ItemAdd Event (Outlook)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869609.aspx)** Occurs when one or more items are added to the specified collection. This event does not run when a large number of items are added to the folder at once. This event is not available in Microsoft Visual Basic Scripting Edition (VBScript).</sub>*
>
> ---
>
> *<sub>**[Application.Startup Event (Outlook)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869298.aspx)** Occurs when Microsoft Outlook is starting, but after all add-in programs have been loaded.</sub>*
>
> ---

Comment: Thanks, it seems I wasn't using the mailitem properly. It seems to work fine now!

Answer (score 1):

Items.ItemAdd and NewMailEx do not work when you have more than 8 items coming in. Microsoft does not guarantee that it will trigger this event itself.