# How can I fix an error that happens when the computer is locked?

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to auto-forward my Outlook email to another email address using VBA code.

I get an error if the macro runs for a while when my computer is locked.

Once the error happens, the macro stops and I don't get email forwarded anymore until I restart the macro. I added the macro to the quick access toolbar. I just close the error and press the macro button.

The macro works fine otherwise.

Here is my code (email@email.com is the email I am forwarding to)

```
Sub Application_NewMail()

Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myInbox = myNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set myemails = myInbox.Items
Set mynewemails = myemails.Restrict("[unread]=true")

Dim x As Integer
For x = 1 To myemails.Count Step 1
If myemails(x).UnRead(True) Then
Dim myMailToFW As Outlook.MailItem
Set myMailToFW = myemails(x)
Set myMailToFW = myMailToFW.forward
myMailToFW.Recipients.Add ("email@email.com")
myMailToFW.Send
myemails(x).UnRead = False
End If
Next

End Sub
```

Edit: The macro seems to run fine. But after a few days or so of running I get an error. This is the error...

Run-time error ' 13':
Type mismatch

If I click debug, I directs me to this line in the script...

Set myMailToFW = myemails(x)

Comment: How do you restart the macro?

Comment: I added the macro to the access bar. I just close the error and press the macro button on the access bar

Comment: Try working with [Application_Startup() & Items_ItemAdd Event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41483071/4539709)

Comment: Edit the question to include the error number and text description. If there is a line highlighted indicate which one.

Comment: The macro seems to run fine. But after a few days or so of running I get an error. This is the error...

          Run-time error ' 13': Type mismatch

If I click debug, I directs me to this line in the script...

          Set myMailToFW = myemails(x)

Comment: To handle the situation where myemails(x) is not a mailitem `If myemails(x).class = olmail then`